# Main title and under it a text in italic

Tags: r, statistics, histogram, italics

I have a question.

I want to add to my histogram, under the main title, another text, but I need this one in Italics, how can I do it? I have this code

```
hist(DataFile, breaks=50, main="Distribucion de Peso\nUca rapax", ylab="Frecuencia de peso", xlab="Peso \n (en miligramos)", col="blue", border="darkblue")
```

I know that the code is `italic(` but I cannot manage where I need to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always add it via `mtext`

```
hist(rnorm(200), breaks=50, main="Distribucion de Peso", 
    ylab="Frecuencia de peso", 
    xlab="Peso \n (en miligramos)", 
    col="blue", border="darkblue")
mtext(expression(italic("Uca rapax")),3,0)
```

[image: title second line italic]